# How do I pass Cypress CLI arguments in the --env with a space?

Tags: javascript, command-line, cypress

I run Cypress from the command line as:

```
npx cypress open --env team=XXXX --config-file my_file.json
```

where my_file.json is my config file and contains:

```
env: {
    "team": ""
}
```

I know that when I pass a value via CLI with no space in it the Cypress runner will show that value in the configuration tab. How do I pass a value such as  to team like:

```
--env team=XXXX XXXX
```

I have tried using `""` and `''` around the argument already and they have not worked. Thank you.

Comment: I am working in Git Bash on Win 10, MINGW64.

Comment: `--env team="XXXX XXXX"` ?

Comment: I want to set the team variable as something with a space in it. XXXX is just representative of some block of text.

Comment: Yes I got that. So what about `--env team="XXXX XXXX"`? Did it work?

Comment: No, passing with double quotes or single quotes did not work on the CLI. That is why I have asked the question :)

Comment: Well you didn't mention you had tried that already...

Comment: My fault, edited the question to include more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to leave this comment here, in case someone else is looking for a solution.

this is what I did, and it worked for me.

in the terminal i'm doing:

```
npm run chat_true -- --env type="dev test"
```

note the "--" before --env

that's the only way I found to overwrite my env value, set in the package.json file like:

```
"chat_true": "cypress open --env type=live",
```

I don't need a space in the middle of the value, so I'm not using a quote surrounding the value, but I just tried it and it worked.

I'm three months late :D

Comment: Double quotes will work for my purposes. Also allows the use of symbols.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-run-env-lt-env-gt), it says "Pass several variables using commas and no spaces". So, off the bat, it sounds like what you're trying to do isn't possible. However, it may be worth a shot to try a different method. In particular, from this screenshot from the link I provided,

[image: snippet]

you can see that the last approach passes a JSON object. Perhaps, if for some reason Cypress parses this JSON object differently, you can try

```
cypress run --env team='{"key": "XXXX XXXX"}'
```

Alternatively, you could also have multiple Cypress configuration files, each with the relevant `team` value. However, if you have multiple `team` values, this simple approach doesn't scale particularly well.